# Creating a Dialpad Using Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently trying to create a dialpad that will print the button pressed in the shell. Here is the code that i have so far:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, RAISED
root = Tk()
buttons = [['1','2','3'],
          ['4','5','6'],
          ['7','8','9'],
          ['*','0','#']]

def clicked():
    print(Button)

for r in range(4):
    for c in range(3):
        button = Button(root,
                        relief = RAISED,
                        padx = 10,
                        text = buttons[r][c],
                        command = clicked)
        button.grid(row = r, column = c)

root.mainloop()

***OUTPUT***
 <class 'tkinter.Button'>
```

When executed the dialpad appears correctly, but when pressing a button the number is not printed in the console, instead the above is printed. Sorry if this is a simple mistake on my part but i am trying to teach myself Python and am still relatively new.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically passing Tk button, but you need to pass the button value, for a safe and good way just use partial

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button, RAISED
from functools import partial
root = Tk()
buttons = [['1','2','3'],
          ['4','5','6'],
          ['7','8','9'],
          ['*','0','#']]

def buttonClicked(buttonVal):
    print(buttonVal)

for r in range(4):
    for c in range(3):
        button = Button(root,
                        relief = RAISED,
                        padx = 10,
                        text = buttons[r][c],
                        command = partial(buttonClicked, buttons[r][c]))
        button.grid(row = r, column = c)

root.mainloop()
```